# proving function is constant using periodicity

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that$$f(x+y)\leq f(x^2+y)$$for all $x,y$.

## solution

Let $0 \le d \le \frac{1}{4}$. Then we can find $x_1$ such that $x_1^2-x_1=d$ and $x_2$ such that $x_2^2-x_2=-d$.
It follows that $f(x+d) \le f(x) \le f(x+d)$ for all $x$ and hence $f(x)=f(x+d)$ for all $x$. So $f$ is periodic with each period in $\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]$ and hence constant.

## question 1

although it is obvious that the function is constant form the periodicity but I wanna know how to prove it rigorously.

## question 2

Instead of saying that the function is periodic can I say every point is a local minimum and therefore it implies that the function is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every number on $[0,\frac  1 4]$ is a period of $f$  then every real number is a period of $f$ becasue any integer multiple of  a period is always  a period. If $x <y$ the $f(x)=f(x+(y-x))$ because $y-x$ is a period so $f(x)=f(y)$. This proves that $f$ is a constant.

Q2: You are probably mistaking $f(x+d) \leq f(x) \leq f(x+d)$ for $f(x-d) \leq f(x) \leq f(x+d)$. We don't get a local minimum from these inequalities. Besides the argument using local minimum doesn't work because $f$ is not given to be a continuous function.

Comment: suppose I have proved that every point is a local minimum (which I think I have proved after a little manipulation), now I don't see why continuity is required??

Comment: @Raunitsingh How do you complete your argument? Why should the function be  a constant if it has  a local minimum at each point?

Comment: f(x)<=f(x+h) and f(x)>=f(x+h)   since both x,x+h are local minimum, therefore f(x)=f(x+h)   and now if we do this repeatedly then it should imply F is constant, I am not sure but it seems correct to me

Comment: The  interval around $x+h$ in which $f(x+h)$ is the minimum value may not include $x$ so ypur argument is not valid.  It is well knwon that there are non-constant functions with a minumum at each point and such examples have appeared on MSE before.  @Raunitsingh